Why does the requestPermissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS) function does not work?
I created an application with a webview in an activity. Inside the activity i wanted to ask user to give the app permission for notifications so that my application can receive notifications from firebase cloud messaging. If the sdk version is bigger than 33 then user was supposed to see a dialog box that asks for the permission but the dialog did not appear.
I saw this piece of code on firebase docs and implemented the code for asking for permissions like below,
private ActivityResultLauncher<String> requestPermissionLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission(),
        isGranted -> {
            if (isGranted) {
                // FCM SDK (and your app) can post notifications.
            } else {
                // TODO: Inform user that that your app will not show notifications.
            }
        }
);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU){
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS) ==
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // FCM SDK (and your app) can post notifications.
        } else {
            // Directly ask for the permission
            requestPermissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS);
        }
    }

I was expecting to see a dialog box that asks user if they allow the app to send them notifications. I debugged my code and saw that the "requestPermissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS);" line was indeed run. But my application did not display a dialog box to me like i saw in the examples. What can be the problem can anybody help me with this ?

Do you have that permission in your AndroidManifest.xml?

It is irrelevant if a box appears or not. Just look if isGranted is true when result comes in.

Yes i have the permission in my AndroidManifest.xml @ianhanniballake

@blackapps I want to show the dialog box to users so that users can give permission in app and they won't need to go to the settings page to do it.

You dont get it. If the box does not come up but the result for isGranted is true then what else do you want?

@blackapps In android 13 phones isGranted returns false unless user gives the permission himself, i want to ask the user if they want to allow the app to send them notifications when they first open the app.

@Brkayy1998 - Is there a chance you already granted this permission? Might need to remove the application and reinstall it.

@tomerpacific - I did not grant the permission. I already removed the app and reinstalled it multiple times.

Hi, did you find solution? I'am facing the same issue

@tomerpacific Yes i did. I was asking checking and asking for multiple permissions back to back. That is why it did not work. I tried asking for multiple permissions using ActivityResultLauncher class and it worked.
